# Micronaut HttpServerFilter: why is the request body is empty?

Tags: http, logging, micronaut

I am trying to log the request body in an HttpServerFilter, but it seems like it is always empty:

[image: 1]

Does anybody know why?

Currently running Micronaut 3.8.5.

Thanks,
Alessandro.

I tried executing both POST, PUT, GET & DELETE requests, but the same happens.
What's strange is that the filter written for HttpClientFilter works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The filter request body will always be empty.

From [Security Documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#securityRule)

> Since version 2.5, the Micronaut Framework executes the filters and then it reads the HTTP Request’s body.

Answer (score 0):

Since Micronaut is built on Netty reading the body is done using asynchronous I/O in a non-blocking manner on demand based on the binding requirements of the controller which can change from method to method. Hence it is not possible to know or to in a manner that doesn't block read the body from a filter.

If you want to log the body you can use a Netty channel handler:

```
@Singleton
class BodyLogger implements BeanCreatedEventListener<NettyServerCustomizer.Registry>, NettyServerCustomizer {

    private static final String BODY_AGGREGATOR = "body-aggregator";
    private static final String BODY_LOGGER = "body-logger";
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BodyLogger.class);
    private final Channel channel;
    private final HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration;

    public BodyLogger(@Nullable Channel channel, HttpServerConfiguration serverConfiguration) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.serverConfiguration = serverConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    public NettyServerCustomizer.Registry onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<NettyServerCustomizer.Registry> event) {
        NettyServerCustomizer.Registry registry = event.getBean();
        registry.register(this);
        return registry;
    }

    @Override
    public NettyServerCustomizer specializeForChannel(Channel channel, ChannelRole role) {
        return new BodyLogger(channel, serverConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStreamPipelineBuilt() {
        if (channel != null) {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
            if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
                pipeline.addBefore(HANDLER_HTTP_STREAM, BODY_AGGREGATOR, new HttpObjectAggregator((int) serverConfiguration.getMaxRequestSize()));
                pipeline.addAfter(BODY_AGGREGATOR, BODY_LOGGER, new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) {
                        byte[] bytes = ByteBufUtil.getBytes(msg.content());
                        String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        LOG.trace("Request {} Body: {}", msg.uri(), s);
                        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I will try this way, then. Since my requirement is to log both incoming requests and outgoing response, is it possible to do the same but for responses, too?